# C# SQL Select from a combobox

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to figure out this:

`sql = "SELECT V_Name FROM  Vendor WHERE V_Ing LIKE '%" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "%'";`

Basically the combobox1 has the different items sold by vendors, so i want this to select the vendor name that sells the product that i pick from the combobox but it wont work. basically the V_Ing is a column with V_Ings separated by a comma, i.e apples, coffe, creamer so I want to populate a listbox with the vendors that sell that one ingredient i selected.

Comment: How do you fill the combobox? This defines what the ToString on SelectedItem will return. Please add that code.

Comment: I fill it when the form loads 
```
 sql = "SELECT Ingredient_Name FROM  IngredientS_Supply";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

            {
                connection.Open();
                command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {

                    comboBox1.Items.Add(dataReader[0].ToString());
```

Comment: You didn't provide enough information. If this is WinForms, you should've included that tag. What database? A tag would've cleared that up too. What results are you getting, and what did you expect? Also, it looks like you actually edited what your code does. Way too confusing for me!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using WebForms? In this case your sql should look like this

```
sql = "SELECT V_Name FROM  Vendor WHERE V_Ing LIKE '%" + 
   comboBox1.SelectedItem.Text + "%'";
```

SelectedItem is an object and ToString will provide wrong value.

IMPORTANT: Instead of embedding values like you do use SQL Parameters!

Answer (score 0):

Use LIKE keyword instead of equal sign:

```
sql = "SELECT V_Name FROM  Vendor WHERE V_Ing LIKE '%" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "%'"
```

Comment: @user121231312312312312 is it sql server?

Comment: and did you debug and see "comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()" has the correct value that you want to use?

Comment: When you debug the code, what is the complete text of the variable: "sql". What is happening when you copy and run it directly in sql server? any error message or no data returns?